# how to add prefix in memcache keys?

Tags: php, memcached

Does anybody know how to add Prefix on each memcache keys? I am working with `zend php`.

I am using `Memcache` not `Memcached`. and i have more than 1000s memcache keys. and i want to add prefix on each of mem keys.

I have googled but could not find anything useful. 
I have two site on same server one is Live Site and another is for staging.

so i want to add `prefix`

```
'staging_' // Stage Site

'live_' // Live Site
```

How can i make this work?

Please help

Comment: If the memcache(d) calls are abstracted out - e.g. with helpers functions or a [DI/IoC] class - then the wrappers can trivially use the appropriate config and perform key "namespacing", but the [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) library itself has no such support AFAIK. (Also, maybe the two environments could/should just use different servers?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can create a class for wrapping `Memcache` class?

Example:

```
namespace My;

class Memcache extends \Memcache
{
    private $prefix;

    public function __construct($prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function add($key, $var, $flag = null, $expire = null)
    {
        parent::add($this->prefix . $key, $var, $flag, $expire);
    }

    public function get($key, &$flags = null)
    {
        return parent::get($this->prefix . $key, $flags);
    }

    // And another methods
}
```

Comment: it means i need to re-create all `memcache keys` with `prefix`. But i don't want to do that. Is there not another way to add prefix? because i have large size of data..